# simple jquery quiz - counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var score = 0;

$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var isCorrect = $(this).data('correct');
    if (isCorrect === 'yes') {
        score++;
    }
    console.log(score);
});
```

There's a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/warrenkeith/2DGj2/1/

I'm trying to construct a basic client-side quiz from the above. My problem at the moment is I don't know how to prevent multiple clicks racking up my score count. If someone selects the wrong answer after clicking the right one then I'll need to deduct the count as well.

I've tried some if statements in there but don't seem to be making much ground! Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using count, just keep the track of selected answers which has the `data-correct=yes`

```
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    console.log($('ul .selected[data-correct="yes"]').length);
});
```

The above code searches for li tags which has the class `selected` and with the data attribute `correct=yes`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2DGj2/3/)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Such an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can close your issue as below:

```
var score = 0;

$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).siblings().hasClass('selected')==false){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var isCorrect = $(this).data('correct');
    if (isCorrect === 'yes') {
        score++;
    }

}
 console.log(score);    
});
```

Updated Code

```
var score = 0;

$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    if($(this).siblings().hasClass('selected')==false && $(this).hasClass('selected')==false){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var isCorrect = $(this).data('correct');
    if (isCorrect === 'yes') {
        score++;
    }

}
 console.log(score);    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2DGj2/4/)

[Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2DGj2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use something similar to your approach, you could use:

```
var score = 0;
$('ul li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var isCorrect = $(this).data('correct');
    if (isCorrect === 'yes') {
        score++;
    } else {
        score--;
    }
    $(this).siblings().unbind();
    console.log(score);
});
```